# mqtt broker windows with arduino client

Tags: ethernet, mqtt, arduino-uno, mosquitto

hey everybody I have a problem that I can't communicate a MQTT broker (mosquitto) on my computer(windows 7 x64) with an arduino-uno client via Ethernet shield, i have already installed the PubSubClient library from knolleary and import it to my IDE of arduino, this is my code-source:

```
 /*
  Basic MQTT example

  - connects to an MQTT server
  - publishes "hello world" to the topic "outTopic"
  - subscribes to the topic "inTopic"
 */


 #include <SPI.h>
 #include <Ethernet.h>
 #include <PubSubClient.h>

 int ledPin = 5;


// Update these with values suitable for your network.
byte mac[]    = { 0x74,0xD0,0x2B,0xEC,0xC3,0xEE };
//@ mac of the arduino in my computer
byte server[] = {192,168,1,4};
//the ip @ of the broker installed in mylocalhost
byte ip[] = {192.168.1.25};
//ip @ of the arduino in my computer



void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
// handle message arrived
Serial.print(topic);

}


EthernetClient ethClient;
PubSubClient client(server, 1883, callback, ethClient);


void setup()
{
Ethernet.begin(mac,ip);
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Ethernet Begin");
if (client.connect("arduinoClient")) {
Serial.println("Client connected");
//client.publish("outTopic","hello world");
//client.subscribe("inTopic");
}
else{
      Serial.println("Client not connected"); 
}
}


void loop()
 {
  client.loop();
 }
```

after running this code "Ethernet Begin" and "Client not connected" are shown, I couldn't unterestand where is the problem and how to solve it.
Thanks in advance;

Comment: Do you really have your Arduino and Win computer on different sub nets? Cause server and Arduino IPs looks strange.

Comment: Can you PING your Arduino from Win computer?

Comment: hi @MichalFoksa, the problem is solved by changing the id address of my arduino but the current problem in th mqtt library on the arduino client, for the publish method is fine but the subscribe nope have you an idea about this ??

Comment: Code mentioned in this question has it solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740560/mqtt-error-void-callback-subscribed-on-arduino/29763710 except network issue which is solved in my answer. Try to combine it.

Comment: hi @MichalFoksa, that does not solve my problem, i want to subscribe in topic on my arduino and recieve message from my mosquitto broker installed on raspberry pi but it still wrong i want to run this instruction in my raspberry:
mosquitto_pub -t inTopic -m test -h 192.168.1.25 (which is the ip address of the arduino ). so i have no result after running this just "Error: Connection timed out" , what is the problem plz

Comment: Use Ip of your mosquitto broker in sub command. All you comunication must go towards broker. Broker then distributes messages to subscibed clients.

Comment: Pub/Sub concept is very well explainef here http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part2-publish-subscribe/ . It is worth to read the whole series of Mqtt.

Comment: I have read this document and I know the different aspects of this protocol, but my problem is how to retrieve the message published by the broker on my arduino i think it is just problem of ip addresses because when i ping to my ip address of my arduino it work fine and if i publish message to topic which my arduino subscribed like this mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.25 -t inTopic -m test : a connection timed out is shown :/

Comment: Right, it is problem of host where you publish. Mesage has to be published to broker running on raspberry. Try this command: `mosquitto_pub -h 127.0.0.1 -t inTopic -m test`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the ip address of my localhost and the ip of my arduino is fixed to be 192.168.1.25 i don't understand what do you want to show me by this example :(

Comment: `mosquitto_pub -h <ip of your MOSQUITTO broker - NOT ARDUINO!!!> -t inTopic -m test`

Comment: ok but i'm subscribed to inTopic from my arduino card so i think to try this :
mosquitto_pub -h <ip of arduino card> -t inTopic -m test,  no ???

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Ardino but
have you turned off the firewall on the Win7 computer running the broker it is probably rejecting port 1883.

https://github.com/francoisvdm/TT3 is a good mqtt client for testing that the broker works from another windows computer.

Comment: the problem is solved by changing the id address of my arduino but the current problem in th mqtt library on the arduino client, for the publish method is fine but the subscribe nope have you an idea about this ??

Answer (score 0):

the problem is resolved because when i connect to the broker with my arduino client I open a session with the broker installed on my raspberry pi so very simple to publish to topics which arduino is subsribe just run this command in the broker like this:
mosquitto_pub -t inTopic -m test; without -h 192.168.1.25 and it works very well, finally thank you very much @Michal Foska